# Real Analysis Question Involving Lp norms

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble with the following question: Let $\{f_n\}$ and $f$ be Lebesgue measurable function on $E$ ,where $m(E) < \infty$. Assume that $f_n \to f$ and $\sup_n \|f_n\|_{L^p(E)} < \infty$ for some $p>1$. Prove that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$ norm. Show by counterexample that this convergence may no longer hold if you replace the $L^p$ condition with $\sup_n \|f_n\|_{L^1(E)}$.

Help please! Even just a hint!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use Egoroff's to get $L^1$ convergence on a set of measure $\mu(E)-\epsilon$. For the set of measure epsilon, use Holder's on $f_n-f$ and your condition. (For the counterexample, all you have to do is look up the famous fact that a.e convergence not implying $L^1$ convergence.)

Comment: Ok i will try this! Thanks